# MVC5-Signal R-Redis Not all messages are received

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr, windows-server-2012-r2

Following this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-with-redis, configured a redis backplane for an existing MVC5 app.

One node is deployed in local IIS, second node is deployed in a windows virtual box. Redis is running in another Ubuntu virtual box.

The problem is, not all messages are received in all browsers (one is local machine, another one is inside the windows VM) and the issue is also not consistent. Sometimes notifications are delivered and sometimes completely not. Sometimes partially delivered.

**UPDATE-1:**

I have created a plain simple working solution by removing all redis, sql server etc etc and worked on a simple message sending app. Using IIS Express i am able to open multiple browsers & multiple tabs and realtime messages are communicated very quickly. However when deployed in IIS (in windows 10 desktop), its limited to maximum of 2 tabs and not working when 3rd tab is opened in browser. (seems like the limitation of 10 max connections we usually see with desktop versions of windows). I have tried settings as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/performance/signalr-performance), but no luck.

However, even when i deployed in Windows server 2012 R2 Datacenter OS, the app is working for maximum of two tabs in the browser but when i opened any third tab, simply the messages are not receiving in those tabs.